# Morphological closing with javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

How would you do morphological closing with JS?

I have tried some known image processing libraries for JS like Pixastic but I cannot find there any related closing function.

Comment: Do you have dilation and erosion available?

Comment: First, thank you for your comment, I wasn't familiar with the above functions, I tried Google and found Processing.js so i'm checking it out right now, it's not really straight forward though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Processing.js, you seem to have dilation and erosion filters available (at least they appear in the [documentation](http://js.processing.org/reference/filter_)). Closing is a combination of these, i.e.:

```
Close = Dilate + Erode
```